# How to not allow special characters to be entered in the address field when a customer is filling out there billing or shipping information

Tags: magento-1.9

Would my edit have to be in the phtml files? All I want to do is add more to the validation process of the address field.

Comment: Street Name validation right

Comment: Follow this http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

Use "validate-alphanum" class in your textbox.
Reference: http://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/